# element function appendchild is null error

Tags: javascript, forms, function, rendering

I am currently trying to create a function that creates a form has a submission button and by default is hidden until triggered from another button. My button currently pops the form up as I would like but within the form my add button is not present and I also can not actually add to the form due to it saying appendChild is null. But checking the server and query all suggest that value was found. Below is my error a the specific snippet and lastly the form I am rendering.

```
getAndFormatNewReviewForm(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       const newReviewForm = document.getElementById('new-review-form')   
       const submitButton = document.createElement("button") 
       submitButton.innerHTML = "Add"
       submitButton.id = "review-submit"
       submitButton.type = "submit"
       const buttonDiv = document.getElementById("buttons")
       buttonDiv.appendChild(submitButton)
       submitButton.addEventListener('click', this.submitReviewInputs.bind(this))
     }
```

[image: javascript]

[image: comment form]

Comment: Are you sure you have an HTML element with `id="buttons"`?

Comment: So you were definitely on to something here I was able to rectify the issue it was a simple typo in html being button not buttons that caused them to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally do not recommend this, but probably somewhere along the line either the async scripts do not run in the intended sequence, or the script tags are not loaded in the intended sequence. Either way, the function you are calling is called before the div element is available. One way is to poll within a reasonable timeframe and then execute your function, once the element is available. For example:

```
function getButton(){
    let poll = (res)=>{
            let div = document.getElementById("buttons");
            if (div) {
                res(div);
            } else {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){poll(res);});
            }
        };
    return new Promise(function(res){poll(res);})
}
```

To use you'd

```
 getButton()
    .then(function(div){ 
          el.addEvenlistener("click",getAndFormatNewReviewForm,false);
    })
```

`div` is "buttons", el would be whatever you attached `getAndFormatNewReviewForm` to. Change "click" to whichever event you want.

Be warned, this is a duck tape solution, you need to also design the script to terminate if necessary.

Comment: Yea but I do see how this would be helpful to use in the future I appreciate this solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

at first you must be get a log (console.log() method ) from  buttonDiv constant if is not null,  change

```
 getAndFormatNewReviewForm(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       const newReviewForm = document.getElementById('new-review-form')   
       const submitButton = document.createElement("button") 
       submitButton.innerHTML = "Add"
       submitButton.id = "review-submit"
       submitButton.type = "submit"
       const buttonDiv = document.getElementById("buttons")
       buttonDiv.appendChild(submitButton)
       submitButton.addEventListener('click', this.submitReviewInputs.bind(this))
     }
```

to

```
 getAndFormatNewReviewForm(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var newReviewForm = document.getElementById('new-review-form')   
       var submitButton = document.createElement("button") 
       submitButton.innerHTML = "Add"
       submitButton.id = "review-submit"
       submitButton.type = "submit"
       var buttonDiv = document.getElementById("buttons")
       buttonDiv.appendChild(submitButton)
       submitButton.addEventListener('click', this.submitReviewInputs.bind(this))
     }
```

i think that will work